# Ajax Posting issues

Tags: php, jquery

I am having issues with my posting ajax am not getting the values in my php

```js
function pending(propid, id) {
  $("#pending").html("<td colspan='4' class='spinner-border'></td>");
  var propid = propid;
  var id = id;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "",
    data: {
      id: id,
      propid: propid
    },
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(propid);
      $("#pending").html(data);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="approve" onclick="pending(<?php echo $rec->id ;?>, 1)">Click</a>
```

Comment: I formatted and added a </a>

Comment: instead leave url blank wyou can past it even if PHP is on the same page you don't see any error on the log or anything that can help to debug this?

Comment: What error are you getting? Where is the php code? is the php echoing propid correctly in the link? The question is not clear.

Comment: Am getting undefined variable on my php page

Comment: $id = $_POST['id'];
   $propid = $_POST['propid'];

Answer (score 0):

You have to properly set your `dataType` and `contentType`

Open your Chrome Network inspector and see what is sent when you run this script:

```js
function pending(propid, id) {
  $("#pending").html("<td colspan='4' class='spinner-border'></td>");
  var propid = propid;
  var id = id;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://n334lkj2334.free.beeceptor.com",
    data: JSON.stringify({
      id: id,
      propid: propid
    }),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(propid);
      $("#pending").html(data);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
}
pending('foo', 'bar');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i just did this now and  $id = json_decode($_POST['id']);
   $propid = json_decode($_POST['propid']);

Comment: The problem is in my url.php page it shows undefined id and propid that's the issue

Comment: Long time I used raw PHP, but you might need to do `$data = json_decode($_POST)` and then access `$data['id']` and `$data['propid']` ? @Dannykeyz